# Getting timeout in FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, c#

I'm trying to get a list of all of the subscribers within a list.  The list is approx 32,000 email addresses.  Below I have my code that makes the first request and it typically succeeds in getting the first set of 2,500.  Then it continues to make subsequent requests, but at some point I get a timeout.  Sometimes after 5,000, other times after 20,000.

I'm using the C# FuelSDK.  I cannot figure out how to make it wait longer than 60 seconds.

```
GetReturn getResponse = getListSub.Get();

AddFromResults(getResponse.Results, ref emails);

while (getResponse.MoreResults)
{
    log.InfoFormat("Emails from ExactTarget: {0}", emails.Count);

    getResponse = getListSub.GetMoreResults();
    AddFromResults(getResponse.Results, ref emails);
}
```